# Flickity slider works only sometimes

Tags: shopify, flickity

Link to store: https://modernstaples.com/pages/our-blankets

Link to demo: http://jameszedd.com/demos/flickity/

The flickity slider works fine on my demo, but when I put the code on the Shopify theme, it displays odd until you do something else on the page, like open Chrome Inspector.

I'm trying to make it look perfect first time out the gate. Any advice on what could be causing the display to act this way until something on the page changes?

Comment: I have analysis your question.further analysis i have not found flickity.min.css & flickity.pkgd.min.js on your  this page https://modernstaples.com/pages/modern-staples  
Please check below screen shot
http://prntscr.com/ibsz85  ( Refer this page source of your working demo url)

Comment: I also tried Slick slider and got an error with that. Looks like the theme is causing JS not to load properly. :(